# Exactly recreating image NetEncoder output

Tags: export, image, neural-networks, implementation-details, python

I need to run an exported NetChain in ONNX, surprisingly the model exports and runs successfully, but there's a discrepancy in the image loading stage (the NetEncoder'ing that must be written manually).

Here's a minimal working example of the issue:

```
Export["oxford.jpg", ExampleData@ExampleData[{"TestImageSet", "Oxford2011"}][[1]]];
encoder = CloudGet @"https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/8af91972-cf2f-4754-9ea7-34d53d8cb312";

correct = encoder @ Import @ "oxford.jpg";
byHandMMA = ImageData[ImageResize[Import@"oxford.jpg", {224, 224}], 
                  Interleaving -> False] - {.48, .46, .4};

Max @ Abs[correct - byHandMMA] (* ok, not zero but small enough... *)
```

[image]

Then here it is in Python:

```
# pip install scikit-image 
import numpy as np
from skimage.transform import resize
from skimage import io

img = io.imread("oxford.jpg")
img = np.rollaxis(img, 2, 0) # uninterleaved
img = resize(img / 255, (3, 224, 224), anti_aliasing=True)
img[0]=img[0]-0.48  
img[1]=img[1]-0.46  # subtracting mean channel values (from NetEncoder)
img[2]=img[2]-0.4
img = img.astype(np.float32)
img
```

Importing back yields a big difference with what it should be:

```
byHandPy = Normal[%];
Max @ Abs[correct - byHandPy] (* 0.125127 *)
```

[image]

Here's another attempt with a different image library:

```
# pip install Pillow
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open('oxford.jpg').resize((224, 224))
img = np.array(img, dtype='float32')/255
img = np.rollaxis(img, 2, 0) # uninterleaved
img[0]=img[0]-.48  
img[1]=img[1]-.46  # subtracting mean channel values (from NetEncoder)
img[2]=img[2]-.4
img
```

Now the error is smaller, but still too big and impacts the network's performance.

```
byHandPy = Normal[%];
Max @ Abs[correct - byHandPy] (* 0.0627451 still too big*)
```

[image]

Perhaps someone knows exactly how NetEncoder["Image"] works (exact resizing method, order, antialiasing options etc..)? I think I'm missing some tiny detail.

**Refs:**

- https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.transform.html#rescale
- https://github.com/onnx/tutorials

Comment: @xslittlegrass Could you help here?

Comment: NetEncoder["Image"] uses OpenCV to load images. The details are hidden in OpenCVLink binary though. The actual call to link is in `OpenCVLink`ImportOps`CVLoadImagesFromPath`.

The following code reveals the call:
`
Trace[encoder[file], OpenCVLink`ImportOps`CVLoadImagesFromPath[___]]
`

Comment: @PavrlPerikov Can you turn this into an answer?

Comment: I provided the answer with some warning below

Answer (score 5):

According to @user5601 suggestion I'm turning my comment into an answer.

`NetEncoder["Image"]` uses OpenCV to load images. The exact implementation is hidden inside OpenCVLink binary library though and deeper in `libopencv_core.dylib`. The actual OpenCV call is `cv::imread` in case you use it as in `NetEncoder["Image"][File["...."]`.

The following snippet reveals the code that calls OpenCVLink:

```
encoder=NetEncoder["Image"];
file = File[...];
Trace[encoder[file], OpenCVLink`ImportOps`CVLoadImagesFromPath[___]]
```

**WARNING**:

Please be aware of the bug in `NetEncoder["Image"][File[...]]` implementation which presents since early 12.x releases (and will be fixed in 13.1): it leaks every image it loads so using it repeatedly in affected versions is impossible — you'll run out of memory pretty soon.

Comment: That's an insanely bad regression

Comment: I was mad about it. It's already fixed but will show only in 13.1